# Why is mat-form-field not editable inside this FormArray?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

The following form does almost what it should do except that I cannot edit any `mat-form-field`s inside it. They are not disabled, it's just not possible to edit them.

What is the reason for that?

See: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ckpey4?file=app/form-field-label-example.html)

I do not see a difference to  [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-example) on StackBlitz.

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray, FormControl} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'form-field-label-example',
  templateUrl: 'form-field-label-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['form-field-label-example.css'],
})
export class FormFieldLabelExample {

  public dataList = [
    {name: 'Alice'},
    {name: 'Bob'}
  ]

  public form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {

    const formArray = this._fb.array([]);  

    for (const data of this.dataList) {
      formArray.push(
        this._fb.group({name: new FormControl(data.name)})
      );      
    }

    this.form = this._fb.group({
      offers: formArray
    });

  }

}
```

```xml
<div>

  <form [formGroup]="form">

    <div formArrayName="offers" *ngFor="let data of form.controls.offers?.value; let i = index;">
      <ng-container [formGroupName]="i">
        <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput placeholder="Name" formControlName="name">
        </mat-form-field>
      </ng-container>
    </div>

  </form>

  <span *ngIf="form.dirty">DIRTY</span>

  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Name">
  </mat-form-field>

</div>
```

Comment: Weird... it's like they're not two-way binding.  You could take out mat-form-field and matInput, and that will at least get your dirty flag to set on the form.

Doing that will give it the same weird behavior the other stackblitz has, where it seems to only want to take one character at a time for me.

Comment: @pmiller3 I just changed the second example which I referenced in my question to use `matInput` and `mat-form-field` ([example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-example-btww2s?file=src/styles.css)) - it's not working there too. I guess that's a bug?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is indeed related to ngFor rendering behavior.

To be more precise, if the array used in ngFor changes the references to the elements of this array(and we didn't provide custom trackBy function to override comparison) then Angular will recognize these changes and rerender the view.
[image]

Angular forms can often trigger `AbstractControl.updateValueAndValidity` method for all hierarhy of controls.

```
FormControl -> parent -> FormGroup -> parent -> FormArray -> parent -> FormGroup
```

For [FormGroup](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/fbff03b4768c1d8b07ab8e54ca28568f78929a36/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L1538) it triggers the following method:

```
_updateValue(): void { (this as{value: any}).value = this._reduceValue(); }
```

which basically create a new object, i.e. `{name: 'Alice'}` The next time it is triggered it will override current value with a new one.

```
{name: 'Alice'} !== {name: 'Alice'}
```

That's exactly that Angular default differ recognizes in ngForOf directive.

### You may ask?

Then why don't I see a difference to [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-example) on StackBlitz?

In that example the problem is still there but can't be seen at the first glance.

```
|username  password
  /\
click here(it works)

username  password
            /\
     then click here(it doesn't since the dom was rerendered)
```

The difference between your example and the example above is that you use material controls and the trigger of `AbstractControl.updateValueAndValidity` happens earlier.

### So what's the solution?

1) The mentioned before trackBy property

```
trackByFn(index) {
  return index;
}

*ngFor="let data of form.controls.offers?.value; let i = index; trackBy: trackByFn"
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ckpey4-c8yigk?file=app/form-field-label-example.ts)**

2) Assign `this.form.controls.offers.value` to component property and use it.

```
arr;
...
this.arr = this.form.controls.offers.value;

*ngFor="let data of arr; let i = index;"
```

[**Stackblitz Example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ckpey4-afkpmk?file=app%2Fform-field-label-example.ts)

Comment: This answer deserves an award. Not only the inputs work, also the `dirty` flag gets set correctly. I think thanks to this I won't have to hack around with `@ViewChildren` and ugly update-logic! Thanks man!

Comment: It turns out the problem occurs when using `offers.value` - switching to `offers.controls` solves the problem too. Adding a [Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ckpey4-ffmokt) for the record (source [github](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/16000)).

Comment: That's because controls remain the same after `updateValueAndValidity` call

Comment: Something to be aware of, the syntax for trackBy is `trackByFn(index: any, item: any)`. This allows you to then track by a unique id from the item, rather than just using the index.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed your code and now it works.
Check it please. If it's not what you exactly want, maybe you can find some idea on it to solve your problem.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ckpey4-bxiidz?file=app/form-field-label-example.html

Comment: It's possible to edit the inputs but the FormArray does not get marked as dirty anymore. That's actually why I want to use it.